# C - make watchpoint with assembly

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, watchpoint

Like what gdb do with watchpoint, I want to put a watchpoint programmatically in C. I heard that is possible with assembly. In the current time I know only for breakpoints like this instruction :

```
int i=0;
while(1){
    i++;
    if(i >= 10)
         asm("int");/*break*/
}
```

After searching, it exist a possibility to display assembly's instruction using TUI mode and reuse it in my program but it doesn't work.

```
gdb -q ./prog -tui
gdb: TUI mode is not supported
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: that's simple to trigger a breakpoint by calling `int 3`, but a watchpoint is much more complex... I believe the debugger protects the segment and when a page fault occurs on that segment, it checks if the address matches the watched address. Good luck coding that.

Comment: And what is your problem? What is your question? Please take some time to read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What CPU architecture are you using?

Comment: my CPU arch : x86_64

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I made the changement, I hope that is clear !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On x86, to make a hardware watchpoint, you'll need to program one of the debug registers. You can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register).